# Using RSync to copy a sequential range of files

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, rsync

Sorry if this makes no sense, but I will try to give all the information needed!

I would like to use rsync to copy a range of sequentially numbered files from one folder to another.

I am archiving a DCDM (Its a film thing) and it contains in the order of 600,000 individually numbered, sequential .tif image files (~10mb ea.).

I need to break this up to properly archive onto LTO6 tapes. And I would like to use rsync to prep the folders such that my simple bash .sh file can automate the various folders and files that I want to back up to tape.

The command I normally use when running rsync is:

```
sudo rsync -rvhW --progress --size only <src> <dest>
```

I use `sudo` if needed, and I always test the outcome first with `--dry-run`

The only way I’ve got anything to work (without kicking out errors) is by using the `*` wildcard. However, this only does files with the set pattern (eg. `01*` will only move files from the range `010000 - 019999`) and I would have to repeat for `02`, `03`, `04` etc..

I've looked on the internet, and am struggling to find an answer that works.

This might not be possible, and with 600,000 .tif files, I can't write an exclude for each one!

Any thoughts as to how (if at all) this could be done?

Owen.

Comment: You can match all files with the most simple globing expression `*`.  If this matches too many files, you'll need to tell us what other patterns you want to exclude so we can help you narrowing your match.

Comment: @5gon12eder OK, I'm new-ish to Linux so not sure what globing is...... In terms of files, they are named with the convention 'legendary_dcdm_3dXXXXXX.tif'  (Where X is a number)... I would like to move say 20 -50K files into separate files, which a) breaks up the size of the folder such that it will Fit onto a LTO6 Tape and b) makes it easier if a restore ever where needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globing is the feature of the shell to expand a wildcard to a list of matching file names.  You have already used it in your question.

For the following explanations, I will assume we are in a directory with the following files:

```sh
$ ls -l
```

```
-rw-r----- 1 5gon12eder staff 0 Sep  8 17:26 file.txt
-rw-r----- 1 5gon12eder staff 0 Sep  8 17:26 funny_cat.jpg
-rw-r----- 1 5gon12eder staff 0 Sep  8 17:26 report_2013-1.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 5gon12eder staff 0 Sep  8 17:26 report_2013-2.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 5gon12eder staff 0 Sep  8 17:26 report_2013-3.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 5gon12eder staff 0 Sep  8 17:26 report_2013-4.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 5gon12eder staff 0 Sep  8 17:26 report_2014-1.pdf
-rw-r----- 1 5gon12eder staff 0 Sep  8 17:26 report_2014-2.pdf
```

The most simple case is to match all files.  The following makes for a poor man's `ls`.

```sh
$ echo *
```

```
file.txt funny_cat.jpg report_2013-1.pdf report_2013-2.pdf report_2013-3.pdf report_2013-4.pdf report_2014-1.pdf report_2014-2.pdf
```

If we want to match all reports from 2013, we can narrow the match:

```sh
$ echo report_2013-*.pdf
```

```
report_2013-1.pdf report_2013-2.pdf report_2013-3.pdf report_2013-4.pdf
```

We could, for example, have left out the `.pdf` part but I like to be as specific as possible.

You have already come up with a solution to use this for selecting a range of numbered files.  For example, we can match reports by quater:

```sh
$ for q in 1 2 3 4; do echo "$q. quater: " report_*-$q.pdf; done
```

```
1. quater:  report_2013-1.pdf report_2014-1.pdf
2. quater:  report_2013-2.pdf report_2014-2.pdf
3. quater:  report_2013-3.pdf
4. quater:  report_2013-4.pdf
```

If we are to lazy to type `1 2 3 4`, we could have used `$(seq 4)` instead.  This invokes the program `seq` with argument `4` and substitutes its output (`1 2 3 4` in this case).

Now back to your problem: If you want chunk sizes that are a power of 10, you should be able to extend the above example to fit your needs.

Comment: question is, what happens when I want a range? Using your example: I want to list report_2013-2 and report_2013-3 when the file contains 600,000 report_2013 files.... expand that to a range of 50,000 files from those 600,000

Comment: `legendary_dcdm_3d45*.tif` will expand to `legendary_dcdm_3d450000.tif` … `legendary_dcdm_3d459999.tif`.  Introduce a variable `i` that counts from 00 to 99 and use `legendary_dcdm_3d$i*.tif` inside a loop.

Comment: Using this, for my needs works a treat! being new to shell and bash, I didn't know the best way to loop..... c/c++ I could do EASY, just not shell/bash.  I am still intrigued by the first suggestion, but in all honestly, I didn't understand it enough!!

Comment: Does this not do what you want? `for i in $(seq -w 0 99); do rm -f MANIFEST.$i; for f in legendary_dcdm_3d$i*.tif; do echo $f >> MANIFST.$i; done; done`  (It will create 100 manifest files in the current directory, each listing the files in the respective range.)

Comment: And I cannot stress this enough: **If you are experimenting with the shell (especially if you are not sure), by all means, don't mess with your production data. Or you might loose it all due to a silly typo!**

Comment: yes i do know what you mean! I always test with -dry-run, and anything with RM in it I stay away from! In this case, Legendary: Tomb of the Dragon.... anyways, the DCPs were made a long time ago the dcdms aren't vital as long as all the dcp's are safe. even then Pro-res Movs are more useful!

Answer (score 3):

You can check for the file name starting with a digit by using [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html):

```
for file in [0-9]*; do
    # do something to $file name that starts with digit
done
```

Or, you could enable the `extglob` option and loop over all file names that contain only digits.  This could eliminate any potential unwanted files that start with a digit but contain non-digits after the first character.

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in +([0-9]); do
    # do something to $file name that contains only digits
done
```

- `+([0-9])` expands to one or more occurrence of a digit

### Update:

Based on the file name pattern in your recent comment:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in legendary_dcdm_3d+([0-9]).tif; do
    # do something to $file
done
```

Comment: You need the enable the extglob option for that

Comment: This is useful to know!!! Thanks, however, as I responded to a comment, the files are in the format : _legendary_dcdm_3dXXXXXX.tif_ so how do you adapt this to accommodate the fact that there is a text beginning?

Comment: @OwenMorgan I've updated the post to match file names of the format provided in your comment.

Comment: @JohnB  I'm confused........ I used the code you wrote, added `rsync -rvhW --progress --size-only $file /000000-050000_test` and no tif were moved..... I used the following range `010000-050000` (leading 0's appear in the file names

Answer (score 0):

old question i know, but someone may find this useful. the above examples for expanding a range also work with `rsync`. for example to copy files starting with a, b and c but not d and e from dir `/tmp/from_here` to dir `/tmp/to_here`:

```
$ rsync -avv /tmp/from_here/[a-c]* /tmp/to_here
sending incremental file list
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
alice/
bob/
cedric/
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0

sent 89 bytes  received 24 bytes  226.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing to LTO6 tapes, you should consider including "--inplace" to your command. Inplace is meant for writing to linear filesystems such as LTO